# Recordset returns the correct number of row but with all field empty

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ms-access, recordset

I have the same copy of access running in 3 cities right now. They work perfectly ok. They are 99% the same with one minor difference. Each of them has two views which use different odbc connection to different cities DB (all these databases are SQL Server 2005). The views act as datasource for some two very simple queries.

However, while I tried to make a new copy for a new city, I found that one of the simple internal query returns the correct number of row but all data are empty while the other query functions correctly.

I checked the data of these two views, the data is correct.

The one causing problem are like

```
Select * from View_Top where Name = "ABC"
```

when the recordset returns, even rs!Name give me an empty string.

Please help

Comment: Please post the definition of VIEW_TOP and any views it depends on.  You are probably using an OUTER JOIN and pulling the columns from the wrong side of the JOIN.

Comment: While it's not likely the cause of your problem, NAME is a reserved word in Access/Jet/ACE and it's a good idea to avoid the reserved words. Variations in the version of Access installed could lead to different results from this kind of problem on different PCs. But this is more a general recommendation, rather than a likely cause of the problem.

Comment: From this location, can you run the same query from MS SQL Management Studio and get results?

Answer (score 0):

Well the query looks a little wrong to me, try using ' instead of " to delimit your ABC string...

Answer (score 0):

Without the definition of VIEW_TOP it's hard to tell where your error is, but if you're getting rows but the columns are NULL I'm guessing that VIEW_TOP (or something it depends on) includes an OUTER JOIN and you're pulling the columns from the wrong side of the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

view_top definition

"Name, Account, AccountCode, Amount, Date...."

Select Statements:

```
Select Name, Account, AccountCode, Amount, Date 
From View_Top Where Name = 'xxx'
```

I found that if I omit the Amount, everything works.

Though I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    acc.FIRM,
    acc.OFFICE,
    acc.ACCOUNT,
    a.CONV_CODE,
    a.OTHER_AMT AS AMOUNT,
    a.TRANS_DATE,
    a.DESCRIPTN,
    a.JRNAL_TYPE
FROM AccTrans AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN ACC AS acc ON a.ACCNT_CODE = acc.ACCNT_CODE
WHERE
    (acc.SUN_DB = 'IF1') AND
    (ANAL_T0 <> '')  AND
    (a.TRANS_DATE < '20091022') AND
    (a.JRNAL_TYPE = 'MATCH');
```

This is the definition of the view. Indeed, in Access i am able to view the result of this query, it has data. that's why i know the recordset returns the correct number of row (by counting the loop in the code). sorry for my mistakes, i use Account in the where clause, the select statements should be like

```
select Firm, Office, Account, Trans_Date.... from
view_top
where account = 'ABC'
```

the query returns the right number of row but all row data (even the account field) are empty string.

then i found out what really cause the problem is the AMOUNT field, if i omit the amount, everything works. though i don't understand why.